# How to post automatically using PHP ?

Tags: php

I've 3 pages:

1. Buy.php
2. payment-try.php
3. payment-ok.php

User buy a product via buy.php.

Buy.php post some values( user_email, amount etc)  to payment-try.php .

In payment-try.php my payment gateway try to make payment. If it is successfull i'll go to payment-ok.php .

The problem is that i don't know how to pass (post) values from payment-try to payment-ok .

This is my sample code from payment-try.php

```
    $user_email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['paidAmount'];
    $payment_token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    try {
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            'amount' => 50,
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'description' => 'My product name',
            'source' => $token,
        ]);

        // Here: if payment is ok i need to go to payment-ok.php PASSING all values (user_email, payment_amount ) etc
    }
```

**So, how to automatically post via Php ?**

Comment: Are you sure your payment gateway doesn't have all that information for you.  Most of them give pretty explicit instructions (with examples) on how to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two ways to do this thing.

1- You have to add hidden input fields in center pages and finally post data on payment-ok.php.

2- You have to set the values payment-try.php into session and use it on payment-ok.php.